# Web server returns .php pages slowly (20+ sec) but .html and .jpg files return quickly: Everything was OK yesterday, no changes (Linode, Ubuntu, LAMP)

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, linode

EDIT/UPDATE: The problem was on Linode's end. The solution was to ignore them telling us that something was wrong with our configuration, and to complain till they fixed whatever was wrong with that server. They insisted they couldn't help us because all they do is keep the servers functioning without getting into what is on the client's choice of contents and setup. But after the boss spoke with the right person, the server was running better than ever with no major changes from us. Thankful for the fix, but also disappointed that we spent nearly a week losing traffic, and stressing out over something that wasn't our fault.

Original Post:

We have a web server at Linode, running Ubuntu and LAMP config. On Tuesday, everything was relatively okay, but on Wednesday morning the Apache server started returning web page requests very slowly.

Something is not going well with processed pages -- specifically with .php pages.

However, a request for the same page saved as "example.html" returns quickly, and so do image files like .jpg.

We run WordPress for most of our pages, but not all. And whether it is WordPress or not, a scripted .php page is returning slowly.

What can I look for to diagnose and resolve the problem, please. Thanks!  (Sorry if this is the wrong community -- point me to another if necessary).

It does not appear to be a network problem, or problem with the html code or elements on the page.

Tried creating .html pages that are not being parsed/processed, and they return very quickly.

But .php pages are very slow. Even the simplest example page -- like  -- is returning with the same 20 second or more delay.

I've done sudo apt-get update and upgrade and upgrade dist commands. Rebooted the Linode, restarted mysql and apache. The sluggish response problem remains.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please also post your complete PHP configuration request.